# Enabling typographic features in iOS system font for body text style

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, uifont, typography

I’d like to modify the San Francisco font by enabling OpenType features it supports, such as [one storey a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A#/media/File:LowercaseA.svg) or [opened four and six](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogG7Z.gif). This setting should apply to *body text style only*.

Text style is *set in Storyboard* attributes inspector and *not in code*.

The code below, for some reason, isn’t working:

```
let bodyFontDescriptor = UIFontDescriptor.preferredFontDescriptor(withTextStyle: .body)
// This isn’t working either: let bodyFontDescriptor = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body).fontDescriptor
let oneStoreyAFontDescriptor = bodyFontDescriptor.addingAttributes(
    [
        UIFontDescriptorFeatureSettingsAttribute:
        [
            [
                UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey: kStylisticAlternativesType,
                UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey: kStylisticAltSevenOnSelector
            ]
        ]
    ]
)
textView.font = UIFont(descriptor: oneStoreyAFontDescriptor, size: 0.0)
```

What am I doing wrong? Generally, is this the right approach?

Comment: unable to understand **one storey a or open four and six**.

Comment: @dahiya_boy Example of [open four and six](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogG7Z.gif). Example of [one storey a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A#/media/File:LowercaseA.svg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to play around selectors. After combining `Six` and `Seven` alternatives the following code have started working:

```
let six = [UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey: kStylisticAlternativesType,
                       UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey: kStylisticAltSixOnSelector]
let seven = [UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey: kStylisticAlternativesType,
                         UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey: kStylisticAltSevenOnSelector]
let descriptor = UIFontDescriptor.preferredFontDescriptor(withTextStyle: .body).addingAttributes([UIFontDescriptorFeatureSettingsAttribute: [six, seven]])
let font = UIFont(descriptor: descriptor, size: 0.0)
label.font = font
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why I wasn’t able to apply font attributes to a text style. I had the checkmark checked for `Dynamic Type Automatically Adjusts Font` in *Attributes inspector* of a view. This somehow interfered with activation of font features that were set in code.

[image: dynamic type automatically adjusts font]